# Learning Probability in R

Tags: r, count, probability, probability-distribution

I'm self-teaching R over here, and have a problem in DataCamp that I don't understand the solution to. When you run `count()`, I understand that it counts the frequency of each category, but does it automatically create a new column, `n`, as well?

```
    size_distribution <- restaurant_groups %>%
    count(group_size) %>%
    mutate(probability = n / sum(n))

    size_distribution
```

Comment: Yes it does! You can try it out and see! Run the line `restaurant_groups %>% count(group_size)` to see the result of `count()`.

Comment: Some of the best advice you can get as a new learner is "just try it". If you don't use a `<-` assignment operator, R will print the result without saving the change to any of your objects, so there no risk of messing things up by trying out commands.